# vim sass.vim load time

Tags: vim, time, load, profiling

I run vim in profiler mode `vim --startuptime vim.log`

```
188.898  000.073  000.073: sourcing /home/slavik/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/perl.vim
188.991  000.063  000.063: sourcing /home/slavik/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/php.vim
189.069  000.047  000.047: sourcing /home/slavik/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/puppet.vim
189.143  000.045  000.045: sourcing /home/slavik/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/python.vim
189.226  000.054  000.054: sourcing /home/slavik/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/ruby.vim
1516.865  1327.610  1327.610: sourcing /home/slavik/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/sass.vim
1517.095  000.170  000.170: sourcing /home/slavik/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/sh.vim
1517.225  000.082  000.082: sourcing /home/slavik/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/tcl.vim
1517.318  000.061  000.061: sourcing /home/slavik/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/tex.vim
1517.397  000.048  000.048: sourcing /home/slavik/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/xhtml.vim
1518.369  1331.773  002.261: sourcing /home/slavik/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic.vim
```

And find very long load sass.vim

It source:

```
if exists("loaded_sass_syntax_checker")
    finish
endif
let loaded_sass_syntax_checker = 1

"bail if the user doesnt have the sass binary installed
if !executable("sass")
    finish
endif

"use compass imports if available
let g:syntastic_sass_imports = ""
if executable("compass")
    let g:syntastic_sass_imports = system("compass imports")
endif

function! SyntaxCheckers_sass_GetLocList()
    let makeprg='sass '.g:syntastic_sass_imports.' --check '.shellescape(expand('%'))
    let errorformat = '%ESyntax %trror:%m,%C        on line %l of %f,%Z%m'
    let errorformat .= ',%Wwarning on line %l:,%Z%m,Syntax %trror on line %l: %m'
    let loclist = SyntasticMake({ 'makeprg': makeprg, 'errorformat': errorformat })

    let bn = bufnr("")
    for i in loclist
        let i['bufnr'] = bn
    endfor

    return loclist
endfunction
```

What wrong with this file?

Comment: Have you checked the `system()` time? I guess an external executable may be a problem.

Comment: Are you sure Pathogen is doing its job? All those checkers are not supposed to be loaded at startup: only `syntastic.vim`.

Comment: @romainl Why are you thinking it is pathogen? Vundle [saves in the same location](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle/blob/3bf598d169993d703c21115876c36e460a51b100/doc/vundle.txt#L88), VAM can be [configured](https://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-manager/blob/c30898da4681779e6b81bf9dfdd2a1262d817ee8/doc/vim-addon-manager-additional-documentation.txt#L216) to do the same thing.

Comment: You are right, of course, but Pathogen is the one that introduced the `~/.vim/bundle` directory IIRC so I went for the lowest hanging fruit. I should have written "your plugin manager".

Comment: @romainl I did some research (no plugin managers I know are going to load something from non-standard directory) and it appears that OP is using outdated version of syntastic ([at least <2.0.0](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/2e7d73305b70a456abb20b1754e094cccfefa3d3/doc/syntastic.txt#L444)). Aside from changelog entry syntax_checkers/sass.vim has slight changes; this particular version was added 31 Jan 2011 and replaced 11 May 2011. Version 2.0.0 is from 02 Dec 2011.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should update syntastic: in the 2.0.0 changelog entry there is

> Only source syntax checkers as needed - instead of loading all of them when vim starts